# Looking for a vim command to insert a character on certain lines

Tags: configuration

There may or may not have been asked before, but I don't know enough about vim to be able to look. How can I add add single quotes (') 5 characters into the line and at the end of every line that begins with a (-)

An example from the file is

```
       want quotes
    here     &      here        
     v               v
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.motd
    - essentials.rules
    - essentials.spawn
    - groupmanager.notify.self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
:%s/^    -\(.*\)/    -'\1'/
```

Adjust the exact number of spaces you need as required.

This searches for the start of a line `^`, then four spaces, a dash, and then uses a *capturing group* to capture all the characters to the end of the line. Then it's replaced with four spaces, a dash, a single quote, `\1` is the contents of the capturing group, then a final single quote.

The leading `%` applies this command to all lines in the file.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks a million

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to "accept" the best answer using the check box to the left. That helps other people know that your problem has been solved.